# general error saving Object repository in UFT

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

When I try to save the shared object repository in UFT, I get an error msg stating "A general error occurred while trying to save the object repository".

I am the only person using this repository..so read write conflicts also does not occur..Please help.

UFT Version : 12.01

Comment: Try saving the file with a different file name?  Then delete the original from Windows Explorer, and rename the saved file

Answer (score 0):

Simplest option is close your UFT and open it again , then you would be able to save it with the same name which you have given earlier. sometimes we used to get this kind of error in 12.01 or in 12.02.

Comment: I have tried it. I have even tried reinstalling UFT again..But am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Open your object repository in Object Repository manager and export the repository to xml and then import from same xml that you've created and save it with new name. I've tried this way and issue got resolved.But this will create new OR .You will have to associate this new OR to already existing Action to which corrupted OR is associated